# Water left unopened

Tags: halacha, animals, geography, pikuachnefesh-danger-life, water

According to this [article from the Kof-K](http://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=uncovered%20water%20snakes&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.kof-k.org%2Farticles%2F040208030446W-33%2520Uncovered%2520Beverages.pdf&ei=Z2FLVZzwJLK07Qbi7YHwDw&usg=AFQjCNEacC2McN-yhF_et8eosgTLF332-A&sig2=FB9u-NmTejAuEB4Vu8hEfw&bvm=bv.92765956,d.ZGU) one is obligated in covering water bottles, but we dont practice today as snakes are not common, but what if i lived in a desert like city, like Phoenix Arizona, should I make sure to cover my bottles of water? Is there still a reason nowadays to be concerned for snakes?

Comment: MOKAY, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for bringing  this interesting question here! I hope you'll look around and find other information of interest, perhaps starting with some of our other 200 [tag:animals] questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you must cover them where snakes are common. The Shulchan Aruch Yoreh Deah [siman 116 siff 1](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.116.1) says explicitly the leniency is only because snakes were not common amongst them.

Comment: Is a modern house even in, say, Phoenix AZ considered a place where snakes are common?

Comment: @Double from the beginning of the Taz I would guess so. But from the tosafos in the first chapter in Chulin where snakes have super powers to go through dirt but not keilim, I would guess not. In general i always thought the Mechaber was a chidush. He lived in Israel and he is quoting European Rishonim.